# Plot large data with 7000 clustering

Tags: python-3.x, pca, word2vec, tsne

I have very large data and I used word2vec for clustering. I have half-million data and those are clustered into 7000 groups.

How can I plot this big number of groups with different color codes? I tried using PCA and tSNE, the main problem is here it is not possible to give unique color for 7000 different groups. I used random hex code for generating color and after plotting, it's not possible to differentiate each group.

[image: output of my plot]

Comment: This is not a programming question, it's a conceptual problem. You have to think about which part or aspect of the 7000 data points you want to present because showing everything will not yield anything useful, as you've seen.

Comment: Indeed, I doubt any creative color-choices will make a plot of 7000 high-dimensional points, algorithmically reduced to just 2D, show anything interesting. Something with far fewer points might start to reveal some relationships, or something with explicitly engineered meaningful axes. For example, maybe one axis is "similarity with reference concept A", & antoher is "simialrity with reference concept B". Then, even a dense cloud of unlabeled points *might* show some vague relationship. (But even that might just be a noisy way of reporting the inherent similarity or difference of A/B.)

Comment: One approach would be to try to reduce the number of groups using a [unsupervised clustering approach](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html). Then, using these groups as new labels, try to illustrate relations between them, and also check for "purity" i.e., how mixed are the new groups with the old.